# how to make a main php file in apache without SQL or database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache

Sorry if i seem impertinent, but i really don't get something with apache or PHP and servers in general. I want, as a try to understand, to make a really basic website that attribute an ephemeral ID to every user (not a session). The ID would be generated onload and deleted when the user quit the page.

Is there a simple way to declare just a main PHP array (that store all user ID) and make it available, alterable for everyone? How to?

EDIT:
i have an other exemple, a range input that modify a div background-color. when someone modify this div background-color with his own input the change impact everyone else. What is the simplest way to store the background color on a global PHP variable ?

Comment: How are you trying to use the ID? Like what is the point of having an array of all 'user IDs' that are actively on the page. Is this some sort of chat system? I guess that's why you're trying to delete it when they leave the page?

Comment: My personals goal are useless at this point i guarentee. Is it possible ?

Comment: php/apache can't keep variables long-term without a database, or using files. (this is one of many reasons why php is dumb). one thing you can do is make a file called 'my-array' and read/write to it on every request to keep a shared array of ids

Comment: session? http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: thank you. can i declare this global array directly in the webpage index, like with all the html and js ?

Comment: Again, it depends on **how** you're trying to use these IDs, but if you only need to display different content per user, you can use a session. Assuming you need "alterable" IDs, this can't be done with raw PHP; you're going to need a database, as you need something to **store** the changes. Either that or allow users to read and write from a file on your server, which is far more dangerous.

Comment: EDIT: i have an other exemple, a range input that modify a div background-color. when someone modify this div background-color with his own input the change impact everyone else. What is the simplest way to store the background color on a global PHP variable ?

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for what is called a `session`, there is documentation on it from PHP at http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php.

To start a session, when the user navigates to the page you would want to have `session_start()` at the beginning of the page.

For basic information on how to start a session, you can check out the documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Is there a way for a session to access other user session variables directly? For exemple, a website were a list of connected users is displayed and every user pick a color with an input. The result is a webpage that display the color of the user melt with the next one on the list. So every user would acces his mate pickedColor like: $_SESSION["pickedColor"]="green" +$_SESSION.mateID"pickedColor"]="red";

Comment: Is this kind of thing is possible without a database?

Comment: This answer points in the right direction, but please include some sample code that shows HOW your solution works.

Comment: http is stateless.  That means every request to a page is brand new; nothing is remembered.  In order to record preferences or other input, you have to use some sort of persistent storage.  Sessions and Cookies are part of the solution, but all they do is store information about how *you* want to interact with a webpage. If you want *others* to see your interaction with the website, it has to be stored somehow, whether in a database or written to a file.  Databases are the preferred way.